# A very simple question on python import, functions, sub-directories

Tags: python, python-import, subdirectory

I have a super simple python project, but I can't get it to work.

In the directory called "demo", I have a file called "demo.py", reading:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from calc import plus
print(plus(1, 4))
```

I also have a sub-directory called "calc" with the following files:

```
__init__.py
minus.py
plus.py
```

The **init**.py is empty, whereas "minus.py" and "plus.py" read respectively:

```
def minus(a, b):
  return a - b
```

and

```
def plus(a, b):
  return a + b
```

When I run the demo.py, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./demo.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(plus(1, 4))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

It must be something absurdly simple, but I just can't figure it out.

Any help and advice would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Yes, you can't call a module. Perhaps what you meant was: `from calc.plus import plus`.

Comment: Your import was wrong.

Comment: Import isn't necessarily wrong.  Call `print(plus.plus(1, 4))` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need fix your import.

You have a file and one function with same name, then you need import the module(file) and after import the function.

```
from calc.plus import plus
```

Or custom your init.py

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html